# Why does the Label text not always start from the same point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` which has 4 lines. Its font size is 15 & `autoshrink` is enabled. It's minimum font size is 10.

When my text is too long then it automatically starts from first line. But when my text is too small then it starts from **`middle line`**.

How can I make sure the text always starts from first line, whether it's too long or too short?

Comment: Use UITextView in place of UILabel

Comment: Indeed UILabel is made for a single line.

Comment: If UILabel is made for a single line why does it have a `numberOfLines` property? ;-)

Comment: How about: UILabel is made for a *fixed* number of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is more a `UITextView` than a `UILabel`.

From Apple's doc :

> UITextView displays a region that can contain multiple lines of editable text.

The *editable* part is optional. You can disable it, along with scrolling if you want to be close to a `UILabel`.